# transition slide in $.mobile.activePage using jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

$.mobile.changePage('#notification', { transition: "slidedown"});

I have the code above using **jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js** and I can see its effects (slidedown) both desktop browser and in android mobile & iphone. But when I used the latest jqm library which is **jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js**, its effect now looks like a fade in and fade out even though I specifically put a slidedown effect. But when view it on an iphone mobile I can see the slidedown effect, you can see this change of effect in desktop or android browser.

Did they change the syntax? Does anyone know about this? or a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery Mobile disables 3d transitions when the view-port is greater than `1000px` (I believe that's the number). So in your desktop browser, just re-size the window to be less than `1000px` wide and refresh the page, 3d transitions should work as they do on your iPhone (if you're using a good browser like Chrome or Safari).

> **Setting a max width for transitions**
>
> By default, transitions can be disabled (set to "none") when the
>   window width is greater than a certain pixel width. This feature is
>   useful because transitions can be distracting or perform poorly on
>   larger screens. This value is configurable via the global option
>   $.mobile.maxTransitionWidth, which defaults to false. The option
>   accepts any number representing a pixel width or false value. If it's
>   not false, the handler will use a "none" transition when the window
>   width is wider than the specified value.

*Source: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/pages/page-transitions.html*

Answer (score 1):

Their blog briefly describes the issue. In order to fix the transition issues with android browsers the JQM team implemented a test to see if the browser can handle 3-d transforms. The iphone passes this test so you are seeing the correct transition. Android 1.x-2.x devices fail this test so their solution was to fallback to just a fade transition.

Comment: i'm using chrome beta. does slidedown transition a 3D effect? I thought they'd be just for pop or flip transition/

Comment: Their docs say that all transitions except fade require 3D transform support.